# How do I search for a specific string inside specific file type

Tags: bash, shell

I've been looking for the answer on google for solid 20 minutes and I cannot find it.. even thought it seems so simple.

All I need to do is search for a string "Eridium" inside a specific directory, and only inside specific file type.

It seems simple but I literally cannot find the answer on any website.. I looked at 10 different tutorials on how to use "grep" or "find" but not a single one has this specific option listed..

Please advice.

Comment: It's lua files so .lua

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
find foo -name '*.lua' -exec grep -Fw -l 'Eridium' {} +
```

Find files with `.lua` extension in directory `foo`, print names of files containing the word<sup>1</sup> `Eridium`.

To supress permission denied errors append `2>/dev/null` to the end.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Word matching is a GNU extension, you may need to remove `w` option to make this work with non-GNU greps.</sub>

Comment: Cool, it works. It throws an error for some reason, but it does work. Got all the files I was expecting. Thank you very much.

Comment: wrt `It throws an error for some reason` - if you told us what the error message is we could probably help with that. No need to escape the `+` btw.

Comment: @SiwyJ you're probably getting a permission denied error, aren't you?